How to correctly collect user-selected images after partial storage access permission on Android 14?
I'm working on an Android app where users can select photos and videos from their gallery.
However, I'm facing an issue on Android 14 (API level 34) with the new partial storage access permissions. After the user grants partial access by selecting SELECT PHOTOS AND VIDEOS, Android automatically shows an image picker.
Unfortunately, I'm unable to correctly collect the images selected by the user in this scenario.

Here's what I've implemented so far:
Statements
private ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia;
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> permissionLauncher;
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityForResult;

Permission check:
public boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
    int statusCode = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return statusCode == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) || checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED)) {
        selectImage();
    } else {
        permissionLauncher.launch(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
                Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED
        });
    }
}

After the permissions, I tried to do the following checks:

If the user only gave partial access:
READ_MEDIA_IMAGES would be false and READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED would be true, then I would search for the photo he selected

If the user accepted all permissions:
Both READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED would be true, so I would show the image selector to him, since in these cases Android 14 does not show it automatically.


permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
    boolean permissionsGranted = false;
    int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    
    if (sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE && (!checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED))) {
        permissionsGranted = true;
        Uri firstImage = selectFirstImageFromMedia();
        if (firstImage != null) {
            setImageInView(firstImage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selection canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE && (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED))) {
        permissionsGranted = true;
        selectImage();
    }
    
    if (!permissionsGranted) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The app needs permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

Other logics
selectFirstImageFromMedia: (Unfortunately they do not work correctly, it seems that the photo returned is always a random one from the chosen ones.)
Refs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/partial-photo-video-access#query-library
private Uri selectFirstImageFromMedia() {
    Uri firstImageUri = null;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID };

    try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " ASC"
    )) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            firstImageUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error retrieving image", " Details: selectFirstImageFromMedia: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return firstImageUri;
}


selectImage
public void selectImage() {
    int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
        pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
                .build());
    } else {
        Intent picIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
        picIntent.setType("image/*");
        picIntent.putExtra("return_data", true);
        startActivityForResult.launch(picIntent);
    }
}

// Logic to collect the image selected by the user on Android 14 or higher.
pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), uri -> {
    if (uri != null) {
        setImageInView(uri);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selection canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

setImageInView
public void setImageInView(Uri uri) {
    try {
        Bitmap fullBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
        Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fullBitmap, ib_tirarfoto_placa.getWidth(), ib_tirarfoto_placa.getHeight(), true);
        ib_tirarfoto_placa.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
        checklist.setVehiclePlatePhotoFilePath(saveImage(fullBitmap));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error retrieving image", "Details: setImageInView: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

Everything works fine when the user grants full access permissions (both READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED). However, when the user grants partial access, Android 14 automatically shows an image picker. In this case, I can't capture the selected image.
I'm particularly confused about handling the image selection after the picker is launched automatically by the system. I tried using selectFirstImageFromMedia() to capture the image, but it often returns a random image instead of the one the user selected.
Any help is very welcome! Thank you in advance!

onRequestPermissionsResult.launch(picIntent); -- this line seems incorrect, or at least has some oddly-named elements. I do not know why you would be using an ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent with something named onRequestPermissionsResult. Beyond that, you have not explained what the problem is with your existing code. "this issue of collecting the image after the selector is launched automatically" -- you should be getting control in your lambda expression for your PickVisualMedia launcher. Is that happening?

@CommonsWare Hi! Thank you for trying to help me. I’ve improved the details and organization of my question. Could you please check it again to see if it’s clearer now?

"it seems that the photo returned is always a random one from the chosen ones" -- well, sure. There is nothing in this code that directly does anything with the response that you got from your pick request. This code relies on the underlying permission grants to limit the overall Cursor response to only those pictures that the user chose. That Cursor knows nothing about the order in which those pictures were selected. Those selections are purely to grant permissions to your app; it does not appear that you find out about the selections directly, let alone their order.

Thank you very much for all your help @CommonsWare! :D

With a little more research and with the help of @CommonsWare, I was able to understand that the automatic selector allows the user to choose one or multiple photos, so it is the developers' responsibility to manage the chosen images in the best way possible.
In my case, I was sorting all the chosen images in ascending order based on the date they were added to the gallery, expecting that only the first one chosen by the user would be collected.
To solve the problem, I simply added a toast that informs the user to choose only 1 image if they have chosen more than 1 in the automatic selector.
Changed codes:
permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
            boolean permissionsGranted = false;
            int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

            if (sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE && (!checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED))) {
                permissionsGranted = true;
                Uri imageFromMedia = selectImageFromMedia();
                if (imageFromMedia != null) {
                    setImageInView(imageFromMedia);
                }
            } else if (sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE && (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED))) {
                permissionsGranted = true;
                selectImage();
            }

            if (!permissionsGranted) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "The app needs permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

private Uri selectImageFromMedia() {
    Uri imageUri = null;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID };

    try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
    )) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select only one photo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            imageUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error retrieving image", " Details: selectImageFromMedia: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return imageUri;
}

